# unable to upload laravel 4 project to server

Tags: laravel

i dont know what's the problem with my folder structure
my folder structure is

```
/
-app
-bootstrap
-vendor
-.gitattributes
-.gitignore
-artisan
-composer.json
-composer.lock
-CONTRIBUTING.md
-phpunit.xml
-readme.md
-server.php
-public_html
   -- //here all the folders and files of public folder
```

i have changed path in bootstrap->path.php  like

```
    <?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here we just defined the path to the application directory. Most likely
    | you will never need to change this value as the default setup should
    | work perfectly fine for the vast majority of all our applications.
    |
    */

    'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Public Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The public path contains the assets for your web application, such as
    | your JavaScript and CSS files, and also contains the primary entry
    | point for web requests into these applications from the outside.
    |
    */

    'public' => __DIR__.'/..',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Base Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The base path is the root of the Laravel installation. Most likely you
    | will not need to change this value. But, if for some wild reason it
    | is necessary you will do so here, just proceed with some caution.
    |
    */

    'base' => __DIR__.'/..',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Storage Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The storage path is used by Laravel to store cached Blade views, logs
    | and other pieces of information. You may modify the path here when
    | you want to change the location of this directory for your apps.
    |
    */

    'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',

);
```

Final changes in public_html->index.php like

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let's turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight these users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can simply call the run method,
| which will execute the request and send the response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have whipped up for them.
|
*/

$app->run();
```

am i doing something wrong please let me know whats wrong in this steps so that i can upload my laravel website to domain serve.

Comment: How are you trying to upload your project to the server? Git? FTP? 
Also, is the server a shared server? SSD cloud server?

Comment: http://www.manavseva.co.in  this is my domain i have uploaded my laravel project to this domain but still it shows blank screen